# SSH fails on macOS Mojave 10.14.1

Tags: macos, ssh, macos-mojave

After updating to Mojave 10.14.1, all ssh connections fail: terminal ssh, scp, git, etc., all get a "broken pipe":

```
 ssh myserver -v
 OpenSSH_7.8p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
 debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/pablo/.ssh/config
 debug1: /Users/pablo/.ssh/config line 137: Applying options for myserver
 debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
 debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
 debug1: Connecting to myserver port 22.
 debug1: Connection established.
 debug1: identity file /Users/pablo/.ssh/myserver.pem type -1
 debug1: identity file /Users/pablo/.ssh/myserver.pem-cert type -1
 debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.8
 debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1
 debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
 debug1: Authenticating to myserver:22 as 'ubuntu'
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
 debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
 debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
 debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
 debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
 debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
 debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:8/V/EyMKSlHjnDpF5v/ume45376635342324
 debug1: Host 'myserver' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
 debug1: Found key in /Users/pablo/.ssh/known_hosts:62
 debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
 debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
 debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
 debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
 debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
 debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
 debug1: Trying private key: /Users/pablo/.ssh/myserver.pem
 debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
 Authenticated to myserver ([xx.xx.xx.xx]:22).
 debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
 debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
 debug1: Entering interactive session.
 debug1: pledge: network
 debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
 debug1: Sending environment.
 debug1: Sending env LANG = es_ES.UTF-8
 packet_write_wait: Connection to 18.203.95.67 port 22: Broken pipe
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

after some research I found that adding this config to my ssh config file makes it work:

```
 Host *
     IPQoS lowdelay throughput
```

Comment: Sounds like your router doesn't recognize [DSCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiated_services). Which is surprising that it's still a problem 20 years later – the router could have just _ignored_ unknown values, like everyone else does, but for some reason it decided to terminate the connection instead. Perhaps it's an "anti-attack" feature gone wrong?

Comment: I have seen some problems with this ssh... And no, I think it's not the router. Other macs and linux in the same network can connect through ssh to the machine I cannot

Comment: How has this not been more publicly known?! Are we the only people in the world that use SSH and Mojave? This broke my Git using GitHub how have we been the only ones with issues?! How does this stuff happen?!

Comment: Just have to say I have two routers and both have had their firmware updated only a month ago. I find it very hard to believe that is the issue. I also have several computers using SSH and only my (just today updated) Mojave Mac has an issue. I cannot fathom why the answer here fixes the issue but it does. Obviously, Apple must have buggered something up.

Comment: @Sukima I think it has to do with the SSH version in Mojave. https://github.com/vmware/open-vm-tools/issues/287

Comment: This also fixed my SSH problem after a 10.14.2 upgrade. Note that it happens on the LAN, too, no routers, so the router explanation doesn't hold water.

Comment: Damn it just got burned by this AGAIN!!!! My Mac ins only ONE week old github worked up till an obligatory update yesterday. Added this answer to my config again and it works. WTF!?! There is no way a new mac is an edge case!

Comment: This solved my issue inside VM ware Player

Comment: I had a similar issue after the Mojave update. For me ssh still worked fine on WiFi, but failed when using my phone's hotspot. This fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with you.
I managed to short term fix it by adding the following option.
`-o ProxyCommand='nc %h %p'`

Comment: This is just a way of avoiding having SSH set the IPQoS flags by using netcat to open the TCP connection instead. the IPQoS solution is more direct.